# Navigator stops working after placing JS

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, css

**UPDATE:**

Hello, I've created a navigation bar witch loads different pages into a div. This is the source for the navigation bar:

```
<div id="navBar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = loadPage('hello-world.html');">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php" onClick="document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = loadPage('hello-world.html');">Staff</a></li>
    <li><a href="goodies.php" onClick="document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = loadPage('hello-world.html');">Goodies</a></li>
    <li><a href="stuff.php" onClick="document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = loadPage('hello-world.html');">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/contact.php" onClick="document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = loadPage('load.php');">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = loadPage('hello-world.html');">Games Center</a></li>
    <li><a href="phptesting.php" onClick="document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = loadPage('hello-world.html');">Habbo</a></li>
</ul>
```

This the div where the text gets placed into:

```
    <!-- Main Body -->
<div id="right">
<a id="bottom">
</div></a>
```

Then this is the javascript witch gets the file and places it into the div:

```
function loadPage(href)
            {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", href, false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                return xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
```

Now, witch these two codes do is when one of the text's for example (Home) gets click, in-between the bottom Div the text loads. When I put this code here to here to load the text when page loads:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        after_load_function(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",filename,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function after_load_function(responseText) {
      document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = responseText;
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      loadXMLDoc("welcome.html");
    }
</script>
```

When I place this It causes the pages not to load any-more. But if I remove it it starts to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your loadPage() function be defined? Does loadPage() function call to loadXMLDoc() function? If so, then:

1- I notice that your ajax callback function do the following:

```
function after_load_function(responseText) {
    document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = responseText;
}
```

2- But, in your loadPage() function, you also did an assign like this:

```
onClick="document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = loadPage('hello-world.html');"
```

However, in your first assign the html content of "right" has been changed. No more "bottom" is existed, so in the second assign an exception will be thrown.

```
<div id="right">
<a id="bottom">
</a></div>
```

I think, that's why your page has stopped to work.

**UPDATE**
With jQuery, you can archive the same result like this:

```
function loadPage(pageToLoad) {
    $.ajax({
        url: pageToLoad,
        complete: function(res) {
            $('#bottom').html(res.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

And then call like this:

```
onClick="loadPage('hello-world.html');"
```

Comment: Right - Let's start with the basics, If you recommended me using jQuery no problem. The one issue would be is you probably have to tell me the source because jQuery is competely new to me.

Comment: Forget about jQuery, just focus to the first part of my post. Does this make any sense to your case?

Comment: function after_load_function(responseText) {
    document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = responseText;
}
Is different to onClick="document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = loadPage('hello-world.html');". There both different and do different things.

Comment: In your page_load event, you call your loadXMLDoc to load welcome.html, this call will remove "bottom" element & might leads to an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use jQuery to make it cross-browser supported? The native js is good, but might not good for cross-browser. Try using the jQuery to see if your issue can be fixed or not.